# How to display a list of departments whose teachers teach DBMS department students?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database in Access. The database has 4 tables:

[DEPARTMENT][image: 1], [TEACHER][image: 2], [LECTURE][image: 3], [SGROUP][image: 4].

I need to display a list of departments whose teachers teach DBMS department students.

The question is: how to do it? I think it should be a query to join multiple times on the same table ... but I don't understand which table to join ...

I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add `DepNo` value which **3**, so the concatenation logically works

`INNER JOIN` displays everything you want about;

*departments whose teachers teach DBMS department students*

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.DepNo, TEACHER.TechNo, TEACHER.name, DEPARTMENT.name, TEACHER.post
FROM DEPARTMENT
INNER JOIN TEACHER ON DEPARTMENT.DepNo=TEACHER.DepNo
ORDER BY TEACHER.name;
```

**Image chart for What's the** `INNER JOIN`:

[image]

**Reference:**

[SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Hello, There was a logical mistake on my query. Now it has fixed. Please check my solution, again. `Orders` isn't define and i wrote it as the reference example. Code logic goes like that **DEPARTMENT** `INNER JOIN`  **TEACHER**.